# Scala: How to fix type mismatch error trying to decode JSON with Circe Decoder

Tags: json, scala, decoder, circe

I need some help with the following situation. I have a JSON API with a registration request. The request takes 4 parameters: Standard phone, password, email, and a person parameter where a customer chooses a type. Based on the chosen type, they have to specify one more parameter: Name or age.

When I get an HTTP request, I need to decode it into my request object. Doing it with the code below results in a compilation error of type:

```scala
type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: io.circe.Decoder[RegistrationReq]
```

Any ideas why that can be the case and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

```scala
import cats.effect.Sync
import cats.syntax.either._
import circe.jsonOf
import io.circe.{Decoder, DecodingFailure, HCursor}
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
import io.circe.refined._
import io.circe.Decoder.Result
import org.http4s.EntityDecoder

trait RegJsonCodec {

  import JsonCodec._ //all common encoders and decoders come from there

  implicit val RegistrationReqDecoder: Decoder[RegistrationReq] = {

    def apply(c: HCursor): Result[RegistrationReq] =
      for {
        phone <- getPhone(c)
        password <- c.downField("password").as[Password]
        email <- c.downField("email").as[Email] //Password and Email are refined Strings
        person <- getPerson(c)
      } yield RegistrationReq(phone, password, email, person)
  }

  private def getPhone(c: HCursor): Either[DecodingFailure, Long] =
    c.downField("phone").as[Long].orElse {
      c.downField("phone").as[String].flatMap {
        str =>
          Either.catchNonFatal(str.toLong)
            .leftMap(e => DecodingFailure(e.getMessage, c.history))
      }
    }.flatMap(phone => Either.right(phone))

  private def getPerson(c: HCursor): Either[DecodingFailure, Person] = {
    c.downField("person").downField("type").as[String].flatMap { type =>

      c.downField("person").downField("name").as[String]
        .orElse(c.downField("person").downField("age").as[String]).flatMap { extra =>

        Either.catchNonFatal(Person.fromPair(type, extra))
          .leftMap(e => DecodingFailure(e.getMessage, c.history))
          .flatMap(person => Either.right(person))
      }
    }
  }

  implicit def requestEntityDecoder[F[_] : Sync]: EntityDecoder[F, RegistrationReq] = jsonOf[F, RegistrationReq]

}

object RegJsonCodec extends RegJsonCodec
```

Comment: The error is here: `implicit val RegistrationReqDecoder: Decoder[RegistrationReq] = {` maybe you wanted to say `= new Decoder[RegistrationReq] = {`